# Giving software sudo permission

Tags: permissions, sudo

I have searched and can't find this. All the folders on my system require sudo permission to edit/save etc... I was wondering if there is a way to give sudo permission to software (geany to be specific) because I'm tired of writing all my code in nano/vim and want to use a better editor. Thank you.

whenever I save in geany I get permission denied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are editing system files, you need to start geany with sudo like so:

```
sudo -i geany /path/to/file
```

or

```
sudo -i geany
```

Comment: @DréEllis just remember that with great power comes great responsibility

Answer (score 0):

Permission denied while you saving means you dont have permission to save the file in that location, you might tried to save your file in root directly which ofcourse requires sudo..

Try below options

1. Use below command to give full permission for that folder where you are trying to save your file to all the user accounts in that system so that you can save without opening your editor with sudo

> sudo chmod 777 (full folder path)

2. Try to save file in your user account specific home or desktop folder, you don't need sudo for this..

Beauty of linux is SUDO. Use it only whereever necessary.

Comment: I have my computer and all files/folders encrypted so 90% of what I do needs sudo. Mchid's answer worked though.